# Инструментальное тестирование в Android

Tags: android, тестирование, ui

Пытаюсь разобраться с темой инструментального тестирования (UI-тестирования) в Android. И можно найти много материала по поводу того, как нужно писать эти тесты, с помощью каких инструментов и т.д. А вот по поводу того, какие именно сценарии использования (use cases) следует тестировать, ничего не могу найти. Т.е. что именно нужно обычно тестировать? Открытие каждого Activity, к какому действию приводит каждое нажатие кнопки? А что ещё? Очень хотелось бы увидеть какие-либо примеры или ссылки на материал, где это описано.

Comment: Могу посоветовать книгу xUnit Test Patterns от Gerard Meszaros

Comment: @A.Shakhov, спасибо! Но книга достаточно большая, может, Вы можете посоветовать, какие именно главы нужно почитать по моему вопросу?

Comment: Не спорю, книга большая, но охватывает все аспекты тестирования. Лучше читать от корки до корки, особенно если хотите качественно разрабатывать через TDD